# Get current theme & Section settings via Shopify API or sync to settings_data.json

Tags: json, shopify, liquid

I am aware of how you can save theme settings in 'styles' (formerly presets) for store owners/managers to choose different presets of theme and section settings made in `settings_schema.json` in another file called `settings_data.json` . However, this requires writing tedious json and is not an option for non-developers. Is there any way to sync current theme & section settings to the `settings_data.json` file, or get the current store settings via the admin or storefront API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that using any API. You can only add/edit code from admin by editing settings_schema.json and settings_data.json file

Thanks